# Multilevel JSON/Nested Dictionaries to JSON

Tags: javascript, python, json, csv

I need to take two tsv files and combine them to make a multi level json which I will use to make a graph.

My edge list however is the limiting factor, meaning I have more nodes in my node csv than I care to graph. I am only concerned with making nodes if they are represented in my edge file.

First I need to read in a smaller 'edge list' tsv.

```
//Example
    source  target  edgeWeight
    NODEA   NODE1   27
    NODEB   NODE2   44
    NODEC   NODE3   28
    NODED   NODE4   46
    NODEE   NODE5   37
    NODEF   NODE6   46
    NODEG   NODE7   58
```

and then I need to check the second csv to see if those nodes are present. If so, I want to add them to elements.node

```
#check to see
//Example
NodeList    edgeWeight
NODEA   7
NODEB   3
NODEC   1
NODEG   9
NODEM   12 // this node wouldn't be created since it isn't present in edges
NODE3   4
NODE4   8
NODE7   1
NODE2   4
NODED   3
NODE1   4
```

And I need my final json file to look something like this:

```
  "elements" : {
    "nodes" : [ {
      "data" : {
        "id" : "NODEB",

       "weight" : 1

      },
    }, {
      "data" : {
        "id" : "NODE3,
       "weight" : 20
        },
    }, {
      "data" : {
        "id" : "NODED",
       "weight" : 60
      },
    }, {
      "data" : {
        "id" : "NODE1",
       "weight" : 80
      },

    }, {
      "data" : {
        "id" : "NODEA",
       "weight" : 100
      },

    } ], 
    "edges" : [ {
      "data" : {
        "id" : "1",
        "source" : "NODEA",
        "target" : "NODED", 
        "weight": 40
      },

    }, {
      "data" : {
        "id" : "2",
        "source" : "NODEG",
        "target" : "NODE2",
        "weight": 4
      },

    }, {
      "data" : {
        "id" : "3",
        "source" : "NODEA",
        "target" : "NODEB",
        "weight": 1
},

    },  ]
  }
}
```

It is for a JavaScript application, though python is okay too.

****************************UPDATE*****************************
Here is some clarification and what I have tried thus far. 
                   Elements
                 /          \
              Node          Edge
               /                \
            data                  data
          /     \           /    \      \
       ID    Weight       Source Target Weight

So far I have been able to create a csv -> pythondict -> json (code below) but only for node and edges, and I'm not sure how to go about combining them.

```
import csv
import json
import sys

Edgecsvfile = open('SmallEdge.csv', 'r')
#creating new to write 
Ejsonfile = open('E2.json', 'wb')

#how to label
Efieldnames = ("source","target","count")
#creating reader 
Ereader = csv.DictReader( Edgecsvfile, Efieldnames)
for row in Ereader:
    json.dump(row, Ejsonfile, indent = 3)
    Ejsonfile.write('\n')


Nodecsvfile = open('SmallNode.csv', 'r')
Njsonfile = open('N2.json', 'wb')

Nfieldnames = ("source","total_mutations")
Nreader = csv.DictReader( Nodecsvfile, Nfieldnames)
for row in Nreader:
    json.dump(row, Njsonfile, indent = 2)
    Njsonfile.write('\n')
```

I then tried nested dictionaries (code below) but I get the error "is not JSON serializable"

```
with open ("ETestjsonfile.json", "r") as myfile:
    Edgedata=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
    print Edgedata

with open ("NTestjsonfile.json", "r") as myfile:
    Nodedata=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
    print Edgedata

    Ndata = Nodedata
    Edata = Edgedata

    target = {'element': {'node': {Ndata}, 'edge': {Edata}}} 


print json.dumps(target, indent = 3)

f = open( 'DICTTEST.json', 'w' )
f.write(repr(target) + '\n' )
f.close()
```

Comment: What are you expecting {NData} to be?

Comment: NData is the node data (dict) that I'm reading in from another file